# Song Identification: The Farm: Angola, USA funeral dirge

Tags: soundtrack, the-farm-angola-usa

It has been many years since I've watched [The Farm: Angola, USA](http://highestcommondenominator.bigcartel.com/category/dvds) (I saw it as an Investigative Reports special on A&E), but there is a song sung by the prisoners as they're burying Bones (that may be off, it could be when they were talking about the funeral or it may not even be that Bones was the inmate who'd died) and also played from an LP, whose label was too fuzzy to read, that I've been trying to source since I first saw this documentary.

The only lyrics I remember are:

> The walls are gone,
>   And I am free.

Even these may not be exact; my memory is pretty terrible.

Comment: You might try rewatching it to see if you can find more info and find the answer yourself.  It's on Youtube, subtitled in Russian. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFqVIlL0A2A

Comment: I'd seen that video but the cyrillics made me skip it (plus it's a copyright violation).  Will have a look when I get some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just perused the video Catjia linked to (the funeral is at the very end), and with the help of Google, the song is **"I'm Free" by Milton Brunson**.

Here are some of the [lyrics](http://www.allgospellyrics.com/?sec=listing&lyricid=12987):

> I am free
>   Praise the Lord, I'm free
>   No longer bound
>   No more chains holding me
>   Soul is resting
>   And it’s just another blessing
>   Praise… the Lord
>   Hallelujah, I'm free
>   I’ve got to say it one more
>
> I am free
>   Praise the Lord, I'm free
>   I’ve been saved and sanctified
>   Filled with His holy holyness
>   I’m resting
>   It's another blessing
>   Praise the Lord
>   Hallelujah, I'm free

Comment: See, I perused the video and couldn't find the funeral! Good for you!